# Is my truth table correct?

Tags: boolean-algebra

[My table on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mw0e2.png)

I am not really sure about the symbols. does the over line mean negation?does the asterisk mean conjunction?if there's mistake, i'd be grateful if someone could upload the corrected table. thanks

Comment: Looks ok to me.  Your understanding of the Line above (Negate) and Asterisk is correct.

Comment: It may seem repetitious to you, but please incorporate the context provided by your title into the body of the Question.  This will frame the specific problem better and likely improve the experience of future Readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols in corresponding standard notation are:
\begin{align*}&+\quad \text{corresponds to}\quad \lor\quad, \quad\text{ "or"}\\ &* \quad \text{corresponds to}\quad \land\quad, \quad\text{ "and"}\\ &\overline{\cdot}\quad \text{corresponds to}\quad \lnot\quad, \quad\text{ "not"}
\end{align*}
Besides that, the table looks correct.

Comment: I'd avoid using tilde (~) here because this is not infrequently used to mean logical negation ("not").